# Magento 2 How to create graphql mutation

Tags: magento2, graphql, table

How to create custom graphql mutation in custom module in magento 2. And how to save custom form data in custom table using mutation.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have create GraphQl mutation for contact us. Please follow below steps.

**Step 1 :-** You Create **`registration.php`** file

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_ContactUs
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mag_ContactUs',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2 :-** create **`etc/module.xml`** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_ContactUs
 */
-->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mag_ContactUs" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_GraphQl"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3 :-** GraphQL queries are declared under **`etc/schema.graphqls`**

```
type Mutation {
    contactusFormSubmit(input: ContactusInput!): ContactusOutput @resolver(class: "\\Mag\\Mohit\\Model\\Resolver\\Contactus") @doc(description:"Contact us form")
}

input ContactusInput {
    fullname: String @doc(description: "The customer's full name")
    email: String @doc(description: "The customer's email address")
    telephone: String @doc(description: "The Telephone")
    message: String @doc(description: "The customer's message")
}

type ContactusOutput {
   success_message: String @doc(description: "Success Message")
}
```

Explaintion of graphqls :-

- type Mutation > declares Mutation operations of our module.
- contactusFormSubmit > name of our Mutation.
- ContactusInput > it is input value and type.
- ContactusOutput > declares output message.

**Setp 4 :-** Create Resolver Class **`Model/Resolver/Contactus.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_ContactUs
 */

namespace Mag\ContactUs\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;


class Contactus implements ResolverInterface
{
    private $contactusDataProvider;

    /**
     * @param
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Mag\ContactUs\Model\Resolver\DataProvider\Contactus $contactusDataProvider
    ) {
        $this->contactusDataProvider = $contactusDataProvider;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $fullname = $args['input']['fullname'];
        $email = $args['input']['email'];
        $telephone = $args['input']['telephone'];
        $message = $args['input']['message'];

        $success_message = $this->contactusDataProvider->contactUs(
            $fullname,
            $email,
            $telephone,
            $message
        );
        return $success_message;
    }
}
```

**Setp 5 :-** Create Data Provider Class in **`Model/Resolver/DataProvider/Contactus.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_ContactUs
 */

namespace Mag\ContactUs\Model\Resolver\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Contactus
{
   /**
   * @var DataPersistorInterface
   */    
   private $dataPersistor;
   /**
   * @var MailInterface
   */
   private $mail;

   private $formKey;
   /**
   * @param
   */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        MailInterface $mail,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
    ) {
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
    }

    public function contactUs($fullname,$email,$subject,$message){
        $thanks_message = [];
        try {
            $this->sendEmail($fullname,$email,$subject,$message);
        }catch (LocalizedException $e) { }
        $thanks_message['success_message']="Thanks For Contacting Us";
        return $thanks_message;
    }
   /**
   * @param array $post Post data from contact form
   * @return void
   */
   private function sendEmail($fullname,$email,$telephone,$message)
    {
        $form_data = [];
        $form_data['name']      =   $fullname;
        $form_data['email']     =   $email;
        $form_data['telephone'] =   $telephone;
        $form_data['comment']   =   $message;
        $form_data['hideit']    =   "";
        $form_data['form_key']  =   $this->getFormKey();

        $this->mail->send(
            $email,
            ['data' => new DataObject($form_data)]
        );
    }
  /**
  * get form key
  *
  * @return string
  */
  public function getFormKey()
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }
}
```

**Setp 6 :-** Final step you check output. Run this query

```
mutation {
    contactusFormSubmit(
        input:{
            fullname: "Mohit Patel"
            email: "magmohit@gmail.com"
            telephone: "+123456798"
            message: "Hi i am testing Graphqls Mutation"       
        }
    ){
        success_message
    }
}
```

**`Output`**

[image]

Second Module I have make save data in my custom table. Please check below codes.In my custom table want to save product details and form data.

**Step 1 and Step 2 :-** Your create **`registration.php`** and **`module.xml`**. Both file code i have defind above.

**Step 3 :-** GraphQL queries are declared under **`etc/schema.graphqls`**

```
type Mutation {
    customFormSubmit(input: CustomFormInput!): CustomFormOutput @resolver(class: "\\Mag\\CustomForm\\Model\\Resolver\\CustomFormInput") @doc(description:"Notify your interest")
}

input CustomFormInput {
    product_id: Int @doc(description: "The Product Id")
    product_name: String @doc(description: "The Product Name")
    product_sku: String @doc(description: "The Product Sku")
    email: String @doc(description: "The customer's email address")
    mobile: String @doc(description: "The Mobile")
}

type CustomFormOutput {
   success: Boolean,
   message: String
}
```

**Setp 4 :-** Create Resolver Class **`Model/Resolver/CustomFormInput.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_CustomForm
 */

namespace Mag\CustomForm\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlNoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Mag\CustomForm\Model\CustomFormCheck;

class CustomForm implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomFormCheck
     */
    private $customFormCheck;

    /**
     * @param CustomFormCheck $customFormCheck
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomFormCheck $customFormCheck
    ) {
        $this->customFormCheck = $customFormCheck;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        if (empty($args['input']) || !is_array($args['input'])) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__('"input" value should be specified'));
        }

        return $this->customFormCheck->execute($args['input']);
    }
}
```

**Explaintion :-** In this file i have check data exits or not and return custom Form sucess and error message.

**Setp 5 :-** Create Data Provider Class in **`Model/CustomFormCheck.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_CustomForm
 */

namespace Mag\CustomForm\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Mag\CustomForm\Helper\Data;

class CustomFormCheck
{
    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * @param Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @throws GraphQlInputException
     */
    public function execute($data)
    {
        try {
            $this->vaildateData($data);
            $response = $this->helper->executeData($data);
            
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            throw new GraphQlInputException(__($e->getMessage()));
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Handle bad request.
     *
     * @param $data
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    private function vaildateData($data)
    {
        if (!isset($data['email']) ||
            !isset($data['mobile'])
        ) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Must be set required data'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Explaintion :-** In this file i have call helper data file function. In helper **`Data.php`** file i have make **`executeData()`** function in this function i have save custom form data in custom table.

**Setp 6 :-** Final step you check output. Run this query

```
 mutation {
   customFormSubmit(
     input:{
        product_id: 3
        product_name: "Test Prodcut"
        product_sku: "Test Prodcut"
        email: "magmohit@gmail.com"
        mobile: "11121231"
     }
   ){
        success
        message
   }
 }
```

**`Output`**

[image]

And save in DB.

[image]

**`Check More Links`**

**How to create graphql query :-**
**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351567/85907**

**How to extend/customise existing graphql query :-** **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351571/85907**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I am new to Magento Graphql and I am trying to create mutation and save the data to custom table. Can you please help me to understand how to save the data to the database? Also if you have any kind of documents/blog where I can refer to extend the Graphql mutation on Magento2?

Comment: @Siv let me know which data you need save in db. let me know i can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I have got the solution and got it worked.

Comment: Good.if any need help let me know thanks.