# Magento 2 How to add custom product attribute into existing product graphql query

Tags: magento2, query, graphql

How to add custom product attribute into existing product graphql query in the custom module in Magento 2.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1 :-** You Create **`registration.php`** file

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_ExtendQuery
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mag_ExtendQuery',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2 :-** create **`etc/module.xml`** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_ExtendQuery
 */
-->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mag_ExtendQuery" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_GraphQl"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3 :-** GraphQL queries are declared under **`etc/schema.graphqls`**

```
interface ProductInterface @typeResolver(class: "Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\ProductInterfaceTypeResolverComposite") @doc(description: "The ProductInterface contains attributes that are common to all types of products. Note that descriptions may not be available for custom and EAV attributes.") {
    your_custom_attribute: String @doc(description: "Brand Name based on manufacturer attribute") @resolver(class: "Mag\\ExtendQuery\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\AddCustomAttribute")
}
```

**Setp 4 :-** Create Resolver Class **`Model/Resolver/Product/GetCustomAttribute.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Mohit Patel
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2021
 * @package Mag_ExtendQuery
 */

namespace Mag\ExtendQuery\Model\Resolver\Product;

class GetCustomAttribute implements \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface
{

    public function resolve(
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field $field,
        $context,
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $product = $value['model'];
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
        return $_product->getData('product_name');
    }
}
```

**Setp 5 :-** Final step you check output. Run this query

```
{
  products(filter: { sku: { in: "new testing" } }){
    items {
      your_custom_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

**`Output`**

[image]

**`Check More Links`**

**How to create graphql mutation :-** **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351569/85907**

**How to create graphql query :-**
**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351567/85907**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Yes this works But if I want to work with filters or sort,  I always receive NULL in $args.. Any Solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can just add that attribute in your graphql query like below and it will show up in response:

```
{
  products(filter: { sku: { eq: "24-MB01" } }){
    items {
      sku
      cproduct_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried this in Magento 2.4