# "Cannot query field \"getProductBySku\" on type \"Query\".",

Tags: magento2, api, graphql

I am creating my custom query in GraphQl and getting this error i searched alot but couldnot resolve my errors by the solutions given

My schema.graphq

```
type Query {
    getProductBySku(sku: String!): Product @resolver(class: "Vendor\\GraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\GetProductBySku") @doc(description: "Get product details by SKU")
}

type Product {
    sku: String!
    name: String!
    description: String
    price: Float!
    image: String
}
```

Resolver File

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\GraphQl\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface;

class GetProductBySku implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        $sku = $args['sku'];

        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
            $productData = [
                'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'name' => $product->getName(),
                'description' => $product->getDescription(),
                'price' => $product->getFinalPrice(),
                'image' => $this->getImageUrl($product),
            ];

            return $productData;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null; // Return null or handle the error as needed
        }
    }

    private function getImageUrl($product)
    {
        $image = $product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getFirstItem();
        return $image->getUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: follow this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351566/magento-2-how-to-create-graphql-query